# What is the width of UIAlertController dialog box in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

Is there a specification for the width of UIAlertController dialog box in iOS? Is the size always fixed or varied by screen size? How to get the width?

Comment: It's vary depends on content, mode, device, version of iOS and screen size.

Comment: i'm sure you could get the width after the UIAlertController has been presented by spelunking through the view hierarchy… but why? what are you trying to achieve?